# How to create keyboard shortcut in Explorer (Win10)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, everything

In Windows 10 I have context menu item with which I can search selected file with the Everything app. The command of it is: `"C:\Program Files\Everything\Everything.exe" -name-part "%1"` so it is passing name of the file to the app.

I'm looking for possibility to have exactly the same functionality, but without context menu. I would like to just select the file and press e.g. F7 to use Everything. Is it possible?

EDIT: I created shortcut with the key assigned, so I can call Everything via the F7 button, but when I use the above command in the shortcut Target field it results in a search query like: `nopath:wfn:"%1"`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this may help, but I have a keyboard shortcut set in Everything to open a new Everything window. It is not passing a filename, but I can easily type it in.

I am curious, why do you want the filename to be pasted automatically in the Everything search?

For me, I have enabled REGEX search in Everything, that allows me to search any file in my computer with few characters.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sometimes when I look through some files I want to make sure I don't have a duplicate somewhere on my drives. I can right-click and choose the search option from the context menu, but it would be ideal to press a key on keyboard that would immediately search for such a file in Everything.